# How do you create a javascript object to export via export.module?

Tags: javascript

I have an javascript test class

```
var Test = function() {
    var _object = {} ;
    _object.url = null ;
    return _object ;
}
exports.module = Test ;
```

Which I can then import via

```
var Test = require('./test') ;
```

When I do this however I get an error.

```
var test = new Test() ;
TypeError: Test is not a constructor
```

I'm expecting to have a test instance of Test such that test.url will return null. How would I change the source so that var test = new Test() works without throwing an error?

Comment: Have a look at the documentation: https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use `module.exports` instead of `exports.module`

The way you have it written currently, you'd be able to reference your Test object like so

```
var Test = require('./test');
var test = new Test.module();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing 
`exports.module = Test;`
So what gets exported from `test` is `module` hence, you will have to

`var test = require('./test');
var Test = new test.module();`

If you directly want to use your `Test` class then you can
`module.exports = Test` in your `test.js` file

and then you can directly do
`var Test = require('./test');
var test = new Test();`
where you are importing it.